# Passing function into another function (with parameters)

Tags: javascript, function-pointers

I can't quite seem to figure this out.

I have a function where a parameter `filter` needs to be a function call that accepts an object built within this function:

```
function bindSlider(time, filter)
{

   var values = {
     min : 8,
     max : 9
   };

   filter(values);
}
```

I'm now unsure how to call `bindSlider`, I thought it'd be something like:

`bindSlider(time, function(values) {/*do stuff here and accept values built in bind slider*/});`

but this fails with the error:

> ReferenceError: fliter is not defined

---

I know I **could do**:

```
function filter(values) {

}

bindSlider(time, filter);
```

but I want to declare filter differently for each call so a `function() {}` type pattern is what I'm after.

Comment: write `var aa=filter(values);` don't call method without reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've tested, it does work. Only problem I had was your object used `=` instead of `:`.
Example:

```
function bindSlider(time, filter) {
   var values = {
       min: 8,
       max: 9
   };
   filter(values);
}

bindSlider(10, function(values) {
   var html;
   for (var i in values) {
       html = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
       document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html + '<br />' + values[i];
   }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JqKa/)

Comment: the = instead of : was actually a cut and paste issue. Good to know I'm not barking up the wrong tree. Still having problem in production. Must be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your code so that the object is properly formatted, you might get rid of the error. Oh, and make sure you're correctly passing in `time` to the `bindSlider` function.

```
var values = {
  min: 8,
  max: 9
};
```

So:

```
function bindSlider(time, filter) {

 var values = {
   min: 8,
   max: 9
 };

 filter(values);

}

bindSlider(1000, function (values) {
  console.log(values); // { min: 8, max: 9 }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TG8fP/).